# Can't add a page after in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document and have used text boxes and images on the page. When I try add a page the cursor will only stay at the top so can only add a page before and not after. Can you help? My client wants to use this document as a template to make future documents in same style.

Comment: Welcome to SU. The question could be clearer and more detailed, the Help center [gives good advice](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You don't say whether you're now trying to add the page break after an image or a text box. The likely solution, however, is that you simply need to [anchor it correctly](https://www.helpndoc.com/step-by-step-guides/how-to-insert-anchors/) in the text.

Comment: Select last (bottom) element on the page, right click, right array, CTRL+Enter

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl+End** should take you to the end of the document, after the anchor for any text boxes.

Text boxes, in Word, are unwieldy and can cause problems with document structure. Why are you using them? What is the purpose?
The only reason I can think of that I would want to use them is if they are to have content that flows from a textbox on one page to another.

Text boxes, in Word, are considered graphic elements, outside of the text layer.

Consider using [**tables**](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm) instead. *Link is to my page.*

If you must use Text Boxes, turn on display of [non-printing formatting marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm) including Anchors.

[image: screenshot with marks]

If you have Anchors displayed, when you are in a Text Box you can see which paragraph in the document is actually holding/anchoring it.